# Flask: Cannot redirect to a specific page

Tags: python, flask

I want to redirect the original page which puts a specific photo.
My code is like this

```
@app.route('/description', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def description():

    photo_id = request.args.get('id')
    photo = Photo.query.filter_by(id=photo_id).first()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash('Your comment posted successfully.')
        return redirect(url_for('description'))
    return render_template('description.html', title='Description', photo=photo, form=form)
```

and HTML is like this

```
<tr id="photo_image">
  <td>
    <img src={{ url_for('static', filename='images/' + photo.image ) }} id="photo_image" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

and I want to redirect to the original page like `/description?id=`
but when I tried to `return redirect(url_for('description'))`
It is going to redirect to `/description`
and error happened.
How can I fix this?

Sorry my way to ask the question was bad.
I want to redirect to `/description?id=` page but this way cannot recognize id and redirect to `/description` page and error happens so cannot find the page.
Basically what I want to do is to redirect to the original specific page after validating the submit.

Comment: what kind of error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass `id` also as an argument to the `render_template` function:

```
return render_template('description.html', title='Description', photo=photo, form=form, photo_id = photo_id)
```

Then in your template:

```
<tr id="photo_image">
        <td>
            <img src={{ url_for('static', filename='images/' + photo.image ) }} id={{ photo_id }} />
        </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. My way to ask the question was bad.

Comment: Sorry never mind I solved, I just don't use url_for and redirect to description?id= + photo_id page